# jQuery clear any type of input

Tags: jquery, html, input

Is there any jQuery function or other easy way to clear all kind of inputs like:

```
$('.some-in').clearInput(); 
//clears text value/ clear checkboxes / reset select's options / clear radio buttons / clear textareas.
```

Comment: Just a note: If the starting values are empty, you could benefit of the `<input type="reset">`

Comment: I need to clear only some part of form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prop("checked", false)` (for checkboxes and radio buttons, assuming you want them unchecked) and `val("")` (for everything else). It's tempting to call both on all elements, but that would clear the `value` on the checkboxes/radio buttons, which probably isn't good. Need to leave buttons alone as well. So:

```
$("input, select, textarea")
    .not("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], input[type=button], input[type=submit]")
    .val("");
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
```

Note: I'm not using jQuery's `:radio` and `:checked` above for the reasons cited on their documentation pages (they can't be handed off to the browser's own selector handling).

<s>But see also [Nitin Chaurasia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17964158/157247) for a *much* simpler solution if you're resetting a form to its state defined by the original markup (not necessarily blank, just what it was originally).</s> Ah, in a comment you said you need to do this only for *part* of a form, so that wouldn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
or
$('#form').trigger("reset");
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/atx6W/

Comment: +1 for `reset`! But sadly, in a comment the OP says he needs to do this for only *part* of the form. Still good to have the reminder about `reset`, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form tag, it's better:

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```